# Multiprocess, Forks and Pipes in C

Tags: c, fork, pipe

I posted a question previously about [using fork() and pipes in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13213864/multiprocessing-and-pipes-in-c)
. I changed the design a little bit so that it reads a regular txt file and sorts the words in the file. So far, this is what I came up with:

```
 for (i = 0; i < numberOfProcesses; ++i) {
    // Create the pipe
    if (pipe(fd[i]) < 0) {
      perror("pipe error");
      exit(1);
    }

    // fork the child
    pids[i] = fork();
    if (pids[i] < 0) {
      perror("fork error");
    } else if (pids[i] > 0) {     
      // Close reading end in parent
      close(fd[i][0]);

    } else {     
      // Close writing end in the child
      close(fd[i][1]);

      int k = 0;
      char word[30];

      // Read the word from the pipe
      read(fd[i][0], word, sizeof(word));

      printf("[%s]", word);    <---- **This is for debugging purpose**

     // TODO: Sort the lists  
    }
  }


  // Open the file, and feed the words to the processes
  file_to_read = fopen(fileName, "rd");

  char read_word[30];
  child = 0;

  while( !feof(file_to_read) ){
    // Read each word and send it to the child
    fscanf(file_to_read," %s",read_word);

    write(fd[child][1], read_word, strlen(read_word));
    ++child;
    if(child >= numberOfProcesses){
      child = 0;
    }
  }
```

where `numberOfProcesses` is a command-line argument. So what it does is that it reads each word in the file and send it to a process. This however, does not work. When I print the word in the child process, it doesn't give me the correct output. Am I writing/reading the words correctly to/from the pipes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the words being printed in the wrong order or interleaved?  The thing is that when you write a word to a pipe, you are expecting the process handling that pipe to be scheduled immediately and to print the word.  Then you expect the main process to run again and the next word to be written to the next pipe etc.

But that is not guaranteed to happen. Your main loop might write all of the words to all of the pipes before any of the other processes is scheduled. Those processes might not be scheduled in the order you expect. And the printf calls might interfere with each other so that their output becomes interleaved.

If you really want to do what you set out to, then Posix threads would be better.  If you just wanted to learn something about using multiple processes, then I guess you have :-)

Comment: I strongly suspect this is the main problem - you absolutely need to synchronize your concurrent processes, or the outputs will get "interleaved" with each other (i.e. "scrambled").

Comment: Well this is for an assignment. I'm fairly new to both programming in C and working in a Linux environment. So yes, I HAVE to do this with processes. It would take me less than 2 hrs to write this in C#. But notice that I'm using Emacs as the editor, not Visual Studio, so the whole debugging process is a nightmare.

Comment: @programmer93 If you're used to an IDE, you might as well use Eclipse and CDT.

Comment: ...or run `gdb` under Emacs - `alt-x gdb`

Comment: @WilliamMorris Even if he would do it with threads, he needed to synchronize them.

Comment: @OlafDietsche, sure, but it is easier.

Comment: @WilliamMorris Well, I guess that's why I have seen so many programmers struggle with threads, because it's easier. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In the parent, you write `strlen()` bytes, which might be less than 30 bytes. In the child, however, you always try to read 30 bytes. You also must NUL-terminate the word, otherwise you might see garbage or a runaway string in your `printf()` statement.

In the child, you must either parse and split the input at word boundary or use stdio as [@JonathanLeffler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13215681/1741542) proposed. When you use stdio, you get all this buffering and word reading for free.

```
int n;
char word[31];

/* Read the word from the pipe */
n = read(fd[i][0], word, sizeof(word) - 1);
if (n == -1) {
    perror("read");
    /* do error handling */
} else {
    word[n] = 0;
    printf("[%s]", word);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "parse and split the input at word boundary"?

Comment: You must look for white space in the input buffer (word) and split the string there. Then keep the remaining bytes as input for your next word. Also be aware, that read might return 30 bytes or less, so check the return value.

Comment: Well I'm not getting any white spaces in my inputs. For example, this is my text file:

`Hello this is a sample text file

this file has three lines

this is the third line`

But when I run the program, the output for 3 processes is like this:

`[Helloafilehasthisthird][istextfilelinesthe][thissamplethisthreeislinethiss][Helloafilehasthisthird]`

and so on.

Comment: This is because the three processes are not synchronized. It's like a group of people talking all at the same time.

Comment: @programmer93 Look at my modified answer. You must terminate the word with NUL. The output you get, might include parts of previous reads. But I strongly suggest, you look again at Jonathan's solution.